# How to disable Appium's log call/setup in pytest?

Tags: python, appium, pytest

Im using Appium to write automation for an iOS app, whenever one of the tests fail, pytest also prints out stuff about Appium itself (Screenshot below), and I was wondering how to disable this.

Im using "pytest -v iOS_Sanity" to run my script, I tried adding the '-s' flag for "disable capturing" but it didnt make any difference.

Current output:
[image: output]

What I wish is for the entire "Captured log call" and "Captured log setup" to not be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out the answer, the needed parameter is `--no-print-logs`

Comment: Thank you. It helped me. Is there any documentation for this ? Where can we find these info ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @RonSerruya

this worked great for my case (since the `--no-print-logs` i deprecated)

```
pytest --show-capture stdout -vv
```

all possible arguments are currently (2020):

`no`, `stdout`, `stderr`, `log`, `all`